# Коллизии в map java

Tags: java, коллекции, map

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разрешаются коллизии в HashMap в java и чем отличаются разрешения этих коллизий?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под реализациями коллизий? Может раскроете вопрос и дополните его примерами (с массивами и `LinkedList`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверное, все-таки, не *реализуются*, а *разрешаются*? И не интерфейс `Map<K,V>`, а класс `HashMap<K,V>`? Если все так, то читайте ниже.

Существует два основных способа разрешения коллизий:

1. Метод цепочек. В этом случае корзина (*bucket*) может хранить несколько элементов, и хранятся они, в большинстве случаев, в виде связного списка (*linked list*).
2. Метод открытой адресации. Здесь, при возникновении коллизии, происходит поиск некоторой свободной ячейки, куда и добавляется очередной элемент.

В Java, для разрешения коллизий, используется метод цепочек.

Изначально, корзина  в `HashMap` представляет из себя связный список (*linked list*). При возникновении коллизии, очередная пара добавляется в этот список.

В последних версиях JDK, в случае, если размер связного списка становится более 8 (константа `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD`), то происходит преобразование связного списка в дерево, при этом, найти элемент в `HashMap` в худшем случае уже можно за `O(log(n))`, а не за `O(n)`, как в связном списке.